# problem on declaring winner in a M X N tic tac toe game( c programming)

Tags: c

I made a tic tac toe game and I was having problem about how to win a game of tic tac toe where the number of row, columns and consecutive grids to win the game is entered by the user.
But sometimes after putting 2 consecutive grids to win the game(n), the winner is declared and sometime it does not declare the winners(that's where my problem is)

n is the number of consecutive grids to win the game(entered by user)
r is the number of rows entered by the user
c is the number of columns entered by the user

I have noticed that when you for example if n = 3, and the user enter 3 consecutive x OR o in a row(xxx OR ooo) it will only declare the winner if the first x or o was started at the corner (ex :coordinate (0,0) (0,1) (0,2) will win the game but coordinate (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) will not) same applies if user won by column or diagonal.

If you want to see the full code to try it on your pc please ask me in the comment section.

This is the code I have tried(but the winner is not always declared)

```
int player_won(char letter, int n) 

{
    int r, c;
    int won = 0;

    // Check rows for a win
    for (r = 0 ; r < n ; ++r) 
    {
        for (c = 0 ; c < n ; ++c) 
        {
            if (grid[r][c] != letter) 
            {
                break;
            }

        if (grid[r][c] == grid[r][c + 1]) 
            {
            if (c + 1 == n - 1) 
                {
                    return 1;
                }
        } 
            else break;
    }
    }

    // Checks columns for a win
    for (r = 0 ; r < n ; ++r) 
    {

        for(c = 0 ; c < n ; ++c) 
        {
        if (grid[c][r] != letter) 
            {
                break;
            }
        if (grid[c][r] == grid[c + 1][r]) 
            {
            if (c + 1 == n - 1) 
                {
                    return 1;
                }
        } 
            else break;
    }
    }

    // Checks first diagonal for a win
    for (r = 0 ; r < n ; ++r) 
    {

    if(grid[r][r] != letter) 
        {
            break; 
        }

        if (grid[r][r] == grid[r + 1][r + 1]) 
        {
            if (r + 1 == n - 1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        } 
        else break;
    }

    // Checks second diagonal for a win
    c = 0;

    for(r = n - 1 ; r >= 0 ; --r) 
    {

        if(grid[r][c] == letter) 
        {

            won += 1;
            c += 1;
        }
        if (won == n) 
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expect that (if user enter n = 3), wherever I get 3 consecutive x or o the winner must be declared